# My Format Date Function Doesn't Work In Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, date, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am writing a simple code that converts the date value of the default format(MM/DD/YYYY) of the first textbox into  a different format of(DD/MM/YYYY) of the second textbox based on the Exit Event

For some reason, it ALWAYS returns the date format MM/DD/YYYY.

```
'First Code to convert it into a string

Private Sub date1_Exit(Cancel As Integer)

Dim dat_ed As Date

dat_ed = CDate(Me.date1.Value)

dat_ed = Format(CStr(dat_ed), "d/m/yyyy")

Me.date2.Value = dat_ed

End Sub

'Second Attempt to convert it directly

Dim dat_ed As Date

dat_ed = CDate(Me.date1.Value)

dat_ed = Format(dat_ed, "d/m/yyyy")

Me.date2.Value = dat_ed
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot format a string that looks like a date. It has to be an actual date. So remove the `Cstr`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong on a couple of places, mainly because you're confusing dates and strings formatted as dates.

```
Dim dat_ed As String 'You want this to hold a formatted date, so it's a string not a date
'dat_ed = CDate(Me.date1.Value) 'We can't do this because a string can't hold a date
'So we combine the next two calls
dat_ed = Format(CDate(Me.date1.Value), "d/m/yyyy") 
'No CString in format, we need it to get the date as a date
'Note that / in format means the system date separator, if you want literal slashes, use \/ instead
Me.date2.Value = dat_ed
```

Also note, if your textbox has the Format property set to a specific date format, you need to modify that property, instead of assigning a formatted date to it.

Comment: wow. thank you soo very much! I truly am a beginner in this.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it way too complicated.

*First*, if you have applied a date/time format to the *Format* property of a textbox, Access knows that this is a datetime value.

*Second*, a date/time value carries no format. It is a value.

*Third*, to have a date value displayed in a specific format, apply this format to the *Format* property of the textbox.

Thus, apply the format `d/m/yyyy` (or `d\/m\/yyyy`) to textbox date2. Then:

```vb
Private Sub date1_Exit(Cancel As Integer)

    Me!date2.Value = Me!date1.Value

End Sub
```